# getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/contentslug/[slug]'

Tags: javascript, next.js, contentful

I am running in to an error and i'm not sure why? within my pages directory I have a folder called contentslug within this contains the `[slug.js]`.

I am following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mdx3ywlnzk8

This is the code in `slug.js`

```
import Image from  'next/image'
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer';
  
export default function BlogPosts({ posts}) {

    const {featuredImage, title , information } = posts.fields

    return (
        <div>
        <div>
            <Image
                src={'https:' + featuredImage.fields.file.url}
                width={featuredImage.fields.file.details.image.width}
                height={featuredImage.fields.file.details.image.height}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            {documentToReactComponents(information)}
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
  
export async function getStaticProps({params}) {
    const {items} = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'posts',
        'fields.slug': params.slug
    })

    return {
        props: {posts: items[0], fallback: 'blocking'}
    }
}
```

and this is the component that links to it

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function BlogPosts({post }) {
   
   const {title, information, slug, thumbnail} = post.fields
   
   return (
        <div className="container text-center ">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h4 className=''>{title}</h4>
                    <Link href={'/contentslug/' + slug}>
                        <a className='btn btn-primary text-white'>Read more</a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are following this tutorial and you are on episode 5 that you linked then you should not be editing `[slug]` page yet, it only happens in episode 7 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRF1KBTH15k&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jClk8wl1yJcN3Zlrr8YSA1&index=7

But if you already want to handle that page then you need to add `getStaticPaths` function to generate paths that `getStaticProps` will get:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await client.getEntries({ 
    content_type: "recipe" 
  })

  const paths = res.items.map(item => {
    return {
      params: { slug: item.fields.slug }
    }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

Comment: actually the slugs work before this and thats why im having issues. I added your code above and it threw client is not defined as an error. So, how I fit the code above in to mine?

Comment: I made it to 7 and that's where I noticed this error. At the start he he clicks on the 'cook this' link and goes directly to the slug but for me I get the above error.

Comment: Have you tried to check the lesson code on the Github? https://github.com/iamshaunjp/next-contentful/blob/lesson-7/pages/recipes/%5Bslug%5D.js For example this one is for lesson 7, same file

Comment: yep I missed something! thanks :)